# parse json object in listview in android

Tags: android

I try parsing a single json object and i have a problem. this is my object :

```
public class ParseJSON {

public static String[] ids;
static String[] names;
static String[] usernames;
static String[] emails;
static String[] addresss;
static String[] phones;
static String[] websites;
static String[] companies;

public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
public static final String KEY_WEB = "website";
public static final String KEY_COMPANY = "company";


private JSONArray users = null;

private String json;

public ParseJSON(String json){
    this.json = json;
}

protected void parseJSON(){
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {

        ids = new String[users.length()];
        names = new String[users.length()];
        usernames = new String[users.length()];
        emails = new String[users.length()];
        addresss = new String[users.length()];
        phones = new String[users.length()];
        websites = new String[users.length()];
        companies = new String[users.length()];

        for(int i=0 ;i<users.length() ;i++){

            JSONObject jo = users.getJSONObject(i);
            ids[i] = jo.getString(KEY_ID);
            names[i] = jo.getString(KEY_NAME);
            usernames[i] = jo.getString(KEY_USERNAME);
            emails[i] = jo.getString(KEY_EMAIL);
            addresss[i] = jo.getString(KEY_ADDRESS);
            phones[i] = jo.getString(KEY_PHONE);
            websites[i] = jo.getString(KEY_WEB);
            companies[i] = jo.getString(KEY_COMPANY);
        }
    }

    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So, what is the problem? - You need to say what you actually see, and what you expect to see.  (And what you tried already to resolve it, if you've already eliminated some things)

Comment: `users JSONArray` is null.

Comment: @ParagKadam Please post raw JSON too. Without that we have no way to know if your parsing is correct or not. Also show the code blow how you are calling the class when you receive the json. Another issue is you have `private JSONArray users = null;` but you are no where setting any value in this variable. How do you expect it to be not null?

Comment: Please post your json object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing very big mistake , you define

```
private JSONArray users = null;
```

where are you getting JSONArray users ? first get jsonArray then get jsonObject

Comment: Where you are getting JSONArray users ?

Comment: i get first JSONArray and then jsonObject        thanks  binesh